# Twitpic Upload API

Tags: api, upload, twitpic

Just wondering if there are any rate limits when it comes to uploading images to Twitpic with the API. I find that on the odd occasion the image doesn't upload. Does anyone have any experience with a similar problem or how I might go about fixing it.

- Should also have mentioned the images are around 200KB or less.

Comment: dont you get any kind of feedback from them when you call their API?

Answer (score 1):

There is a 10MB image upload limit:

```
We take GIF, JPG, & PNG images up to 10MB in size, and videos up to 1:30 in length in most formats.
```

Source: http://twitpic.com/upload

It could also be that their API is having issues, which if that's the case you need to pass the error to the user so they know what happened.